# How to get whole data out of callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsonp, jquery-callback

I have written following function which takes a json data from a url.

```
function getWeatherDataForCities(cityArray){
  var arrAllrecords = [];
  var toDaysTimestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) - (24*60*60);
  for(var i in cityArray){

    for(var j=1; j<=2; j++){
        var jsonurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q="+cityArray[i]+"&dt="+toDaysTimestamp;

        $.ajax({
            url: jsonurl,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            mimeType: "textPlain",
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data){
              arrAllrecords[j]["cityName"] = data.list[0].city.name;
              arrAllrecords[j]["weather"] = data.list[0].weather[0].description;

        } });
        toDaysTimestamp = toDaysTimestamp - (24*60*60);
    }   
  }

  return arrAllrecords;  //returning arrAllrecords
}

$(document ).ready(function() {

  var cityArray = new Array();
  cityArray[0] = "pune";
  var arrAllRecords = getWeatherDataForCities(cityArray);
  //Print All records returned by getWeatherDataForCities(cityArray);
});
```

I have written some comments in above code.I have called `getWeatherDataForCities` `function` which returns all records from `url`.I have declared `getWeatherDataForCities` `array` in function.I want to add all returned records in that array.I have tried as above but nothing is getting into `array`.

> In console showing j and arrAllrecords are undefined.

**How to get all records in array from callback function?**

*you response will be highly appreciated*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `getWeatherDataForCities` function won't return anything because ajax operations are asynchronous. You need to use a callback for that.

Modify your function to accept a callback function:

```
function getWeatherDataForCities(cityArray, callback){
    var arrAllrecords = [];
    var toDaysTimestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) - (24*60*60);
    for(var i in cityArray){

       for(var j=1; j<=2; j++){
           var jsonurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q="+cityArray[i]+"&dt="+toDaysTimestamp;

            $.ajax({
                url: jsonurl,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                mimeType: "textPlain",
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data){
                arrAllrecords[j]["cityName"] = data.list[0].city.name;
                arrAllrecords[j]["weather"] = data.list[0].weather[0].description;
                // call the callback here
                callback(arrAllrecords);
               } 
            });
           toDaysTimestamp = toDaysTimestamp - (24*60*60);
       }   
   }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$(document ).ready(function() {
  var cityArray = new Array();
  cityArray[0] = "pune";
   getWeatherDataForCities(cityArray, function(arrAllrecords) {
       // Do something with your data
   });
});
```

Comment: +1 For callback and async/sync words.That is what i wanted.Thank you.

Comment: One more how can i return arrAllrecords from getWeatherDataForCities.As i want it to use as api.I mean i want to call getWeatherDataForCities method like var data = getWeatherDataForCities(cityarry); I hope you getting what i want to say

Comment: You can set `async: false` in your ajax call in your original method. But a callback is the preferred way to do it. And setting `async` to false is deprecated since jQuery 1.8.

Comment: Thanks @Saravana you have saved my Day

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the empty array. When fetching the values it will always return you undefined.

```
var arrAllrecords = [];
arrAllrecords[2]; //undefined
arrAllrecords[2]["cityname"];  //undefined
```

Better you should use array of objects.

I don't know why you have used variable j. The below code works for me.

```
var arrAllrecords = [];

function getWeatherDataForCities(cityArray){

  var toDaysTimestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) - (24*60*60);
  for(var i in cityArray){

    var jsonurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q="+cityArray[i]+"&dt="+toDaysTimestamp;
        $.ajax({
            url: jsonurl,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            mimeType: "textPlain",
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data){

            arrAllrecords.push({
                "cityName" : data.list[0].city.name,
                "weather" : data.list[0].weather[0].description

            });
            if(arrAllrecords.length === cityArray.length) {
                callback(arrAllrecords);
            }
        } });
  }
}

function callback(arrAllrecords) {
    console.log(arrAllrecords);
}


        $(document).ready(function() {

            var cityArray = new Array();
            cityArray[0] = "pune";
            cityArray[1] = "mumbai";
            cityArray[2] = "delhi";
            getWeatherDataForCities(cityArray);


        });
```

Comment: You have written just what i want.But you have removed one loop.That i wanted.ie each record for each day.Json array will look likearrAllrecords.push("25-12-2013":{
                "cityName" : data.list[0].city.name,
                "weather" : data.list[0].weather[0].description

            }, "24-12-2013":{
                "cityName" : data.list[0].city.name,
                "weather" : data.list[0].weather[0].description

            },);. The formate i have written may wrong but i wanted something look like this.Thanks