# Javascript function is not returning a value in AngularApp

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, express

First, sorry for mi bad english.
Well, the problem in this case is a function: 'refresh', the query is responding and returning the values from the database in mysql, but when i try to grab the response and return to another function, is showing me a "undefined" value.. here is the code:

```
function refresh(query){
    var res;
    $http.get('/quaestioJS/'+query).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);  //HERE, THE INFO IS SHOWING CORRECTLY
        res = data;         //HERE 'res' IS NOT GRABBING THE VALUE OF 'data'
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error.");
        console.log(data);
    });
    console.log(res);
    return res;
}
```

UPDATE V1.0

The updated code:

```
function refresh(query){
    $http.get('/quaestioJS/'+query).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        return data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error.");
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Here is showing the variable and the function in code... the response is the same: undefined

```
function find(tabla){
    var x = refresh("SELECT * FROM "+tabla);
    console.log(x);
    $scope.limpiar();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is when the concept of `callbacks` comes into picture. In order to grab the response, you must pass a function / callback / response handler that will provide with you the with the control to manipulate the response.

**The reason why you are getting undefined in your current implementation, is because the execution of your function invoked is completed before the response of the HTTP call appears. That being the case, the returned value will be undefined.**

So, you can grab the response by passing a response handler, like this :

```
    function find(tabla){
        refresh("SELECT * FROM "+tabla, function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.limpiar();
        });
    }


    function refresh(query, handler) {
        $http.get('/quaestioJS/'+query).
        success(handler).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Error.");
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Good, but the same thing, if i try to grab the response from the handler and return the data, is always 'undefined'... i think that i will work with $scope variable for see the data..

Comment: You aren't supposed to return data from the handler. You should either perform all your manipulations from the handler, or invoke some function that does so from the handler. That is the reason why i have moved **$scope.limpiar()** in response handler

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is $http.get is working async. So you are setting the res variable correctly, but when you are console logging res, it happens before the data is returned. so the correct modification is:

```
function refresh(query, callback){
    var res;
    $http.get('/quaestioJS/'+query).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data); 
        res = data;
        callback(res);
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error.");
        console.log(data);
    });

}

function find(tabla){
    var x = refresh("SELECT * FROM "+tabla, function(data){
        console.log(data); 
        $scope.limpiar();
    });

}
```

edit: sorry my first try was a mistake, totally forgot that return would only return out of the success function.

Comment: Yes, but the real problem is that the function is not returning 'data' or 'res' the main response is there, but the return is "not working", my console is showing 'undefined'.. In the initial code, the return is in the end of the function because in other post says that you can't put a return in a callable, but you can grab the value from the callable and return at the end of the function D:

Comment: Because the return is exiting the callback function and not the outer funciton... so to speak. Check this SO, will update mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772502/how-to-get-whole-data-out-of-callback-function-in-javascript